# Combing lists into list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have these lists in Python

```
text_0 = ['Weight','Weight', 'Weight']
text_1 = [['x','y','z'],['x','y','z'],['x','y','z']]
text_2 = [['1','2,','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']]
```

I  would like would to create a new list like this

```
new_list = ['Weight','x','1','y','2','z','3','Weight','x','4','y','5','z','6','Weight','x','7','y','8','z','9']
```

How do I do this in Python?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your case we can do with `python`

```
sum([[x] + [ items for item in zip(y,z) for items in item] 
       for x, y, z in zip(text_0,text_1,text_2)],[])
['Weight', 'x', '1', 'y', '2', 'z', '3', 'Weight', 'x', '4', 'y', '5', 'z', '6', 'Weight', 'x', '7', 'y', '8', 'z', '9']
```